# How many variables can I delete from my data set?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I am running a multiple regression and I have problems fixing the assumptions. Therefore my question is pretty simple:
How many variables can I exclude because of extreme values?
I have a set of about 3600 variables and right now I deleted almost 230. And to predict I most likely need to exclude more than 100 more to get all assumptions in the regression (gvlma) to satisfied.

Is there a general number or percentage that can be excluded without hesitating? If so what percentage or number is it?

Its a general question therefore I did not add any information about my data or anything else.

I started with reciprocal error and used log on the regression (predictor and the predicted variable).

After that the assumptions looked like this:

|  | value | p-value | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Global Stat | 358.628 | 0.0000000000 | Assumptions NOT satisfied! |
| Skewness | 62.2532 | 0.0000000000 | Assumptions NOT satisfied! |
| Kurtosis | 241.218 | 0.0000000000 | Assumptions NOT satisfied! |
| Link Function | 0.867 | 0.3515330983 | Assumptions acceptable. |
| Heteroscedasticity | 54.2889 | 0.0000000000 | Assumptions NOT satisfied! |

After deleting the extreme values the assumptions looked like this:

|  | value | p-value | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Global Stat | 42.196 | 0.0000000151 | Assumptions NOT satisfied! |
| Skewness | 3.630 | 0.0567558318 | Assumptions acceptable. |
| Kurtosis | 2.453 | 0.1173280831 | Assumptions acceptable. |
| Link Function | 2.061 | 0.1510881899 | Assumptions acceptable. |
| Heteroscedasticity | 34.052 | 0.0000000053 | Assumptions NOT satisfied! |

Now I wanted to use BoxCox or something to get Heteroscedasticity but does not change anything.

And for Global Stat I tried distribute the regression normal through z transformation -> also no change.

Boxplotting gives almost the same results as the transformation of mine.

There is autocorrelation and no multicollinearity.

I don't know what to do than just dropping extreme values... Therefore the question of the beginning (if someone has a different approach I would appreciate to know what I could do exactly)

EDIT: I check for extreme values with the following function:

```
unnecessary_data2 <- influence.measures(lm.01)
table2 <- summary(unnecessary_data2)
```

Comment: Specifically what assumptions do you believe this model makes about "extreme values"?  Indeed, what do you mean by "extreme"?

Comment: I added the function to detect the extreme values. Also I could find them with plotting the regression but that would take longer

Comment: This sounds like a typical case of kitchen-sink statistics. Having 3,600 variables in a model  might not seem crazy if you're doing a machine learning model, but excluding variables because they have "extreme variables" never makes sense (except when you use, e.g. 99999 as a missing code).

Comment: Okay? First time I heard that excluding data that has "extreme" values is an issue. But what would you suggest me to do? Because I already tried different approaches (as mentioned). PS: I have panel data and I don't use machine learning or anything like that.

Comment: Read our posts about outliers: usually it is remarked that automatic exclusion of outliers is a poor idea.  In some cases that procedure will produce dreadfully wrong results.  The classic one is ignoring extreme losses in financial market data.